# JavaScript Math.random algorithm in Brave

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, brave, brave-browser

JavaScript Math.random function generates random numbers using PRNGs (pseudo-random number generators). Since 2015, major browser JavaScript engines updated to xorshift128+. My question is does anyone know if Brave also does the same?

Comment: Brave is based on Chromium and uses the same V8 JavaScript engine that other Chromium browsers use.

Comment: …and while of course it would be possible that they did override the implementation of `Math.random` with a different one, this would be extra effort and there's no reason for them to  do it.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect they might have somehow overridden it. I wrote a simple game and while testing in Brave, in two different instances it seems to have generated exactly 50% - 50% win/loss in a game of chance within 27 and 33 iterations whereas Google Chrome or FF didn't do exactly the same until over 150 iterations. I know eventually it would be 50-50 yet...

Comment: UPDATE: I realized I made a mistake gentlemen. The 33 iterations was while testing with Google Chrome. Does this mean this can be pretty much expected with xorshift128+? Guess that is why it's known as "sub par"... your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The response to your question is, yes does the same. Brave is based on Chromium using V8 JS Engine as any other Chromium browser based uses.